# Print sums of all subsets

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, combinatorics

[Print sums of all subsets of a given set](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-sums-subsets-given-set/)

**Problem summary** : Print all subset sums of a given set of integers

My approach is to store previous results and use them to calculate new (similar idea as DP).

#### `SubsetSum.cpp`

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
//using namespace std;

bool isPowerOf2 (long long x)
{
  /* First x in the below expression is for the case when x is 0 */
    return x && (!(x&(x-1)));
}

std::vector<long long> subsetSums(std::vector<int> set)
{
    long long total = 1<<set.size();    //total number of subsets = size of power set = 2^n
    std::vector<long long> sums(total, 0);
    sums[1] = set[0];
    //std::cout << sums[0] << std::endl;
    //std::cout << sums[1] << std::endl;
    int effectiveBits = 1, prevPowOf2 = 1;
    for (long long i = 2; i < total; ++i)
    {
        if (isPowerOf2(i))
        {
            ++effectiveBits;
            prevPowOf2 *= 2;
        }
        //std::cout << "e = " << effectiveBits << "\tp = " << prevPowOf2 << std::endl;
        
        sums[i] = set[effectiveBits-1] + sums[i-prevPowOf2];
        //std::cout << sums[i] << "\n";
    }
    
    return sums;
}
 
// Driver code
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> set = {5, 4, 3};
 
    std::vector<long long> sumsOfAllSubsets = subsetSums(set);
    for (auto sum : sumsOfAllSubsets)
        std::cout << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You can find the code on [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Gaurav-Singh-97/6174257361b6c0e12dfd163d527ada61) and compilation result at [OnlineGdb](https://onlinegdb.com/B1Bj8DuMS).

Along with code, please also comment on the algorithm itself.
Is it advisable to store previous result in practice (since it takes 2ⁿ space)?
Also, is there any scope of improving time or space without trading-off the other?

Comment: My generalization and optimization inspired by this question and answers below: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/225018

Answer (score 10):

## Preface

This is great code.  Your solution is more than \$10^{42}\$ times nicer than the given solutions on the linked page that promote crap like `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  You are already much better than them in this regard.

## The algorithm

Making use of the STL, your algorithm can be simplified like this:

```
std::vector<long long> subsetSums(const std::vector<int>& set)
{
    std::vector<long long> subset_sums{0};
    subset_sums.reserve(std::size_t(1) << set.size()); // to prevent iterator invalidation
    for (int num : set)
        std::transform(subset_sums.begin(), subset_sums.end(),
                       std::back_inserter(subset_sums),
                       [=](number_t prev_sum){ return prev_sum + num; });
    return subset_sums;
}
```

(You need `#include <algorithm>` for `std::transform` and `#include <iterator>` for `std::back_inserter`)  Here, we first push `0` to the list of sums.  Then, for each element \$x\$, we add \$x\$ to the previous sums and push these new sums.  Therefore:

1. The initial list of sums is `{0}`.
2. For the first element `5`, the list becomes `{0, 5}`, where `5 = 0 + 5`.
3. For the second element `4`, the list becomes `{0, 5, 4, 9}`, where `{4, 9} = {0, 5} + 4`.
4. For the third element `3`, the list becomes `{0, 5, 4, 9, 3, 8, 7, 12}`, where `{3, 8, 7, 12} = {0, 5, 4, 9} + 3`.

## Miscellaneous

The common practice is to put a space between `#include` and the header name, as in `#include <iostream>`.  And simply delete `using namespace std;` rather than commenting it out to show you are following good practice :)

You use `int` for the original numbers, and `long long` for the sums.  Don't mix different data types.  Write a type alias like

```
using number_t = long long;
```

And use it consistently throughout your code.  This makes it clear what these types are used for.

`i` should really be of an unsigned type.  And `isPowerOf2` should also operate on an unsigned type.  The `isPowerOf2` function can be made `constexpr`.  And I prefer a looser layout with more spaces and less parentheses:

```
constexpr bool isPowerOf2(std::size_t x)
{
  /* First x in the below expression is for the case when x is 0 */
    return x && !(x & (x - 1));
}
```

`1 << set.size()` potentially overflows.  `std::size_t(1) << set.size()` is better.  For me, it may be better to extract a function and check for overflow:

```
// returns 2^n
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T> && is_unsigned_v<T>, int> = 0>
constexpr T power2(T n)
{
    assert(n < std::numeric_limits<T>::digits);
    return T(1) << n;
}
```

Passing a `std::vector` by value may cause unnecessary copies.  Pass by `const` reference instead.

`return 0;` can be omitted for the `main` function.

## The future

C++20 provides us with [bit manipulation utilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit).  We can replace `isPowerOf2(i)` with `std::has_single_bit(i)` (after you make `i` unsigned).  The aforementioned `power2` function can also be improved with concepts:

```
// returns 2^n
template <std::unsigned_integral T>
constexpr T power2(T n)
{
    assert(n < std::numeric_limits<T>::digits);
    return T(1) << n;
}
```

The algorithm can also be simplified with the [Ranges library](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) and [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front):

```
std::vector<number_t> subsetSums(const std::vector<number_t>& set)
{
    std::vector<number_t> subset_sums{0};
    subset_sums.reserve(std::size_t(1) << set.size());
    for (int num : set)
        ranges::push_back(subset_sums,
            subset_sums | ranges::view::transform(std::bind_front(ranges::plus, num)));
    return subset_sums;
}
```

Comment: Arguably, it makes sense to use a different type for the sum, as it likely has to represent a bigger range.  Unfortunately, we don't know whether `long long` actually does have a bigger range than `int` (both could be simple 64-bit values, for example).

Comment: Great analysis. I now have things to learn about, like `std::transform`

Comment: exponential space algorithms are never "great".

Comment: @WillNess Good point.  I just saw your answer and upvoted.  Although I never said this *algorithm* is great :)

Comment: I've edited, to clarify some points. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is bad. You calculate them all first, and only then print them out. And what if *n* = *20*, or *42*, or *100*? The printout will never start (and the memory will blow up before that, too).

Instead, have your program **create** *n* *nested loops* **at run-time**, in effect enumerating the binary encoding of *2 <sup>n</sup>*, and print the sums out from the innermost loop. In pseudocode:

```
 // {5, 4, 3}
 sum = 0
 for x in {5, 0}:   // included, not included
     sum += x
     for x in {4, 0}:
         sum += x
         for x in {3, 0}:
             sum += x
             print sum
             sum -= x
         sum -= x
     sum -= x
```

You can emulate the loops creation with recursion, coding only one recursive function. Pass it the array (`{5, 4, 3}` in your example) and a zero-based index, and work as shown above with `x in {arr[i], 0}`, making the recursive call with `i+1`, if `i` is in bounds (`i < n`);  or print the `sum` value out, otherwise. The `for` loop can be inlined away as well, since there always are only two numbers to process, `arr[i]` and `0`.

You did say *print*. Storing them is an insanely ginormous overkill.

*edit:*
Thus concludes the algorithmic review, which you did request. No point to reviewing the code when algorithm is unsuitable for the task. Exponential space algorithms are never good when there's a linear space algorithm to be had.

*2022 side note:* `print` can be replaced with any odd [`callback`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+callback) of your choosing (emulating Prolog / nondeterministic programming, somewhat). See also *"recursive backtracking"*. (the linked SO answers of mine are using Lisp mostly, but there's some pseudocode in there as well).

Comment: `You can emulate the loops with recursive function calls.` using recursion, I see how to *not* need different source code for different *n*.

Comment: (Down-voters please comment. The tool-tip I get reads *not useful*.)

Comment: @greybeard that was the point, yes. some languages actually do allow you to create (the equivalent of) nested loops in run time, which is what I meant obviously (by "create"), not the hard coded *n* loops. But in C and derivatives, recursion can do that. -- Re "useful", right now we have an exponential space algo at +9 votes, and a linear space algo at -1. Just NB. -- also, with recursion, `for` isn;t needed, it can be inlined. I wrote it that way so that correctness is self-evident.

Comment: Also, this idea can be generalized with output iterators, so that the caller can customize the output format, or choose to store the results somewhere, etc.

Comment: Using recursion seems like a better idea than my algorithm (same time, less space). But it will also use call stack. Don't we need to consider that? Edit : Sorry, my bad. Call stack will take max n space at any time. Realized after commenting.

Comment: @GauravSingh yes, exactly. it will be linear in size. :)

Comment: @L.F. (yes, exactly! emulating Prolog / nondeterministic programming, somewhat.) otherwise known as ["callbacks"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+callback). (the link is to my answers on SO which are using this technique. both are in Lisp though, although there's some pseudocode :) )

Comment: @WillNess I advertised your answer in my rewrite https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/225018. :)

Comment: @L.F. thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 3):

Said before, but not by me: storing even half of the final result is *not* advisable.

An *n*-bit [Gray-code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) assumes every combination of *n* values of 0 (use for *not included*) and 1 (included) - while only changing *one* bit in every transition:
start with code and sum 0
for the changing bit *i* turning to one, add the *i*th array item
subtract for a change from one to zero

Comment: There are just too many ways to use this in an implementation for me to decide on one, starting with bothering not to limit array length to number of bits in a suitable integer type.